# Clustering with Autoencoder

Tags: cluster-analysis, dimensionality-reduction

I made a model for clustering and it's encoded dimension is about 3000. To check if the autoencoder is well established, I draw a 2d_pca plot and 3d_pca and the plots look nice.
My question is that, what is general way to cluster with this encoded features?

I think about some options:

- First: to use all encoded features.
- Second: to use all encoded pca features.
- Third: to use some encoded pca features explaining almost 70% variance.

I think usual papers don't refer to it.